# How to launch mobile app on mobile site

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am designing my first mobile site for a small local business.

The most two most important features were a built in 'call us' button and a map function.

The phone call part was pretty easy. But the part that I'm confused about is how to get the maps part to work with both iphone and android users. I can find how to do each one specifically, but how do I cause the button to open up the map app for both iphone and android users?

Comment: Well I am not sure about Iphone but I am pretty sure the latest android versions do a check whenever you go to maps.google for instance and ask you if you want to use the app. However I am not sure that is exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: I'm asking, how do i create a button that will launch the map app on both iphone and android phones. I know both can do it. I just dont know how.

Comment: What I meant by the above is you may be able to just have the button link to maps.google for instance and the phone it self should make the suggestion.